# Visualization chart for four dimensional data

Tags: info-visualisation

I am trying to find a way to visualize the data related to road accidents. The data has following dimensions:

> Year Accident happened (Numeric) | Location of Accident (String) |
>   Count of Accidents (Numeric) | Education Level of Driver (String)

I tried using the Google Bubblechart but that expects 3 numeric dimensions and the 4th dimension (can be number/string) is optional. Please suggest which visualization chart can be used for such data. Please note that I need to utilize any library that works on a web page (so not looking for Excel or such like option).

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123767/what-are-some-popular-choices-for-visualizing-4-dimensional-data

Comment: I'm not sure that there is an easily readable visualisation for four-dimensional data. The only way I can think of running it is to have each data point represented by x-pos, y-pos, radius, and colour - the data as read by your users will be largely interpretive - in other words they may be able to roughly compare two points but nothing more precise. On top of that you have to deal with the fact that the accepted colour ranges for data sets are often the same as those confused by colour blind users. I'd rethink the data set - maybe have two charts?

Comment: Although you might just be better off asking over in https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The challenge you will run into is that you have **Temporal Data** (Year of the accident) coupled with BOTH **Categorical Data** (Education Level and Location) and **Continuous Data** (Count of Accidents). This mix of Data Types will make coming with a *meaningful* visualization very challenging if not impossible. May be you should dissect the data to make lower dimensional meaningful visualizations.